# Redirect to a page other than login in Yii 2 behaviors

Tags: yii2

Is there any way to redirect to a page other than login in behaviors method in Yii 2?

My behaviors method content:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'verbs' => [
            'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
            'actions' => [
                'delete' => ['post'],
            ],
        ],
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'only' => [ 'create','update' ],
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'actions' => [ 'create'],
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ],
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'actions' => ['logout'],
                    'roles' => ['?'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

But it redirects to login. I need to specify another redirect page or call:

```
throw new \yii\web\HttpException(403, 'The requested Item could not be found.');
```

Answer (score 21):

You need to change `loginUrl` property of `yii\web\User` class.

If you want to change it globally, edit your config:

```
'components' => [
    'user' => [
        'loginUrl' => ['site/sign-in'],  
    ],
],
```

If you need to change it in the specific controller or action, you can also set it like this:

```
Yii::$app->user->loginUrl = ['site/sign-in'];
```

You need to override `beforeAction()` method in controller where you need to do this. All access chesks are performed in this event.

```
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function beforeAction($action)
{
    if (parent::beforeAction($action)) {
        // If you want to change it only in one or few actions, add additional check

        Yii::$app->user->loginUrl = ['site/sign-in'];

        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

For more details check official documentation about [property](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-user.html#$loginUrl-detail) and [event](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-controller.html#beforeAction%28%29-detail).

Comment: Is there a way to implement this in access control in behaviors function?

Comment: Checked the source code and I think it's not possible. See updated answer.

Comment: So I cannot call a 403 or 404 exception if access is denied?

Comment: With this behavior it should not be done manually. If the access to current action is denied there are two possible cases. If user is guest he will be redirected to loginUrl. Otherwise 403 Exception will be thrown. Both cases are handled automatically.

Comment: I mean there is no way to change loginUrl via behavior parameters.

Comment: Actually I wanted to throw a 403 error instead of redirection to another page. Redirection is second option for me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66601/discussion-between-arogachev-and-user7282).

Answer (score 9):

You can benefit from **[denyCallback()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-filters-accesscontrol.html#$denyCallback-detail)**, as `Yii2`'s official document defines it:

> A callback that will be called if the access should be denied to the current user.If not set, **denyAccess**() will be called.

The signature of the callback should be as follows:

```
function ($rule, $action)
```

where `$rule` is the rule that denies the user, and `$action` is the current action object. `$rule` can be null if access is denied because none of the rules matched.

As an example:

```
'denyCallback' => function($rule, $action) {
        if ($something) {
            //set flash for example
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('key', 'Value');
            //Redirect
            return $action->controller->redirect('action');
        }
        //as a default behavior, it throws an exception
        throw new ForbiddenHttpException("Forbidden access");
 },
```

Comment: I understood the question as changing loginUrl. If you need invert logic for throwing exceptions and redirecting, yes, this closure can be used.

Comment: it does not show 403 error, I used like this 
  'denyCallback' => function ($rule, $action) {
               if(Yii::$app->user->isGuest){
    throw new \yii\web\HttpException(403, 'The requested Item could not be found.');
               }                
                                                                  }

Comment: Dear @user7282 , this is the canonical way to change the ACCESS DENIED  default behavior. What I wrote on my answer is just an example. You can customize `denyCallback()` to do what you want on access denied. For example throwing to `HttpException` or redirecting or adding a log or anything.

Comment: yes, that is what I tried, still does not show a 403 error
[
              'actions' => ['update'],
              'allow' => true,
              
              'denyCallback' => function ($rule, $action) {
               if(Yii::$app->user->isGuest){
    throw new \yii\web\HttpException(403, 'The requested Item could not be found.');
               }                
                                                                  }
              ],

Comment: @user7282 Dear, this function will be called if the access should be denied. You don't need to check it via if statement

Comment: but how that check be done in behaviours() function ?

Comment: if that is the way, then how can I restrict that check to a particular action only, say actionUpdate

Comment: @user7282 You can see that we have an argument called `$action` (second argument). So you can make custom behaviors for different actions.

Comment: when I added denycallback inside access , i am not able to give action name,
'access' => [ 'denyCallback' => function ($rule, $action) {
               if(Yii::$app->user->isGuest){
    throw new \yii\web\HttpException(403, 'The requested Item could not be found.');
               }  } ,             
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'only' => [ 'create','update' ],
            'rules' => [

Answer (score 1):

I'm using yii2-user for user management, and the redirect to login was going to /user/login instead of the yii2-user defined /user/security/login. so my fix was to update the urlManager rules with: '' => 'user/security/'

I guess this could be used also to redirect to some other controller/action other than login.

See [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html).

Comment: The above link dosen't resolve, use [http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html) instead.