# Way to redirect login page if user not login

Tags: redirect, yii2

I want to redirect user to login page if he is not logged on page. But i have actionLogin in my  registrationController

So when I use in my common/main:

```
'as beforeRequest' => [  //if guest user access site so, redirect to login page.
    'class' => 'yii\filters\AccessControl',
    'rules' => [
        [
            'actions' => ['login', 'error'],
            'allow' => true,
        ],
        [
            'allow' => true,
            'roles' => ['@'],
        ],
    ],
],
```

It always redirect me to `index.php?r=site%2Flogin`

Is it possible to change main login redirect to `index.php?r=registration%2Flogin`?

If it possible where I should overwrite code or change something..

`'user' => [ 'loginUrl' => ['registration/login'], ],`

resolve problem but when I want to go to registration/index to signup user it redirect me to registration/login.

Is it possible to rule out this url from being enforced? I Want to make `index.php?r=registration` the only available path.

And here is my facebook login; I want to enable this too

```
public function oAuthSuccess($client) {
        // get user data from client
        $userAttributes = $client->getUserAttributes();

        $user = User::find()->where(['Email' => $userAttributes['email']])->one();

        if (!$user) {
            $newuser = New SignupForm();
            $newuser->oAuthSuccess($client);
            $user = User::find()->where(['Email' => $userAttributes['email']])->one();
            if ($newuser->validate() && Yii::$app->getUser()->login($user)) {
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', Yii::t('app', 'Udało się poprawnie zalogować. Prosimy dokonać zmian w ustawianiach profilu.'));
                return $this->redirect('index.php?r=content/news');
                }
        }
        
        Yii::$app->user->login($user);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `app/config/web.php` (for basic template) or
`app/frontend/config/main.php` (for advance template) - [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27408064/redirect-to-a-page-other-than-login-in-yii-2-behaviors)

```
return [
    // ...
    'components' => [            
        // ...
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'common\models\UserIdentity',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
            'loginUrl'=>['registration/login']
        ],

        // ...
```

and in your controller for eg `RegistrationController.php`

```
// ...
class RegistrationController extends Controller
{    
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(),                
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'actions' => ['login', 'signup'], // those action only which guest (?) user can access
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['?'],                        
                    ],
                    [
                        'actions' => ['home', 'update'],  // those action only which authorized (@) user can access
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['@'],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'logout' => ['post'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    // ...
```

Comment: ok i resolved it but what about facebook login? I Edit my post where i show Yuo function to login with facebook which not working

Comment: What is the issue with facebook login, please give detailed info

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is using index.php from backend web or public directory

```
<?php

// comment out the following two lines when deployed to production
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');

require __DIR__ . '/../../vendor/autoload.php';
require __DIR__ . '/../../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php';

$config = require __DIR__ . '/../../config/web.php';
$config["controllerNamespace"]='app\controllers\backend';
(new yii\web\Application($config))->run();

if(Yii::$app->user->isGuest){
    $request_headers = apache_request_headers();
    $srv=$request_headers['Host'];
    header("Location: https://".$srv);
    die();
}
```